# Can java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close cause android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-networking

The App works fine on the 2.2.1 and 2.2 but is causing the following error on 4.0.3

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:175)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.exhaustInputStream(ChunkedInputStream.java:289)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.close(ChunkedInputStream.java:262)
at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:179)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:266)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:64)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.close(InflaterInputStream.java:256)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close(GZIPInputStream.java:148)
at com.myapp.apper.contact.ContactService.a(SourceFile:390)
at com.myapp.apper.contact.ContactService.a(SourceFile:347)
at com.myapp.apper.contact.ContactService.a(SourceFile:41)
at com.myapp.apper.contact.g.a(SourceFile:322)
at com.myapp.apper.contact.q.a(SourceFile:58)
at com.myapp.apper.contact.q.onPostExecute(SourceFile:23)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

All my network operations are in AsyncTask and from the stacktrace looks like the errors is caused by `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close` and it also points towards the like 390 of the code which is `gzipIn.close();`.

Is GZIPInputStream causint this error? If not, what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Your `GZIPInputStream` is connected to some `org.apache.http` `InputStream` which itself seems to be reading the remaining data from a `Socket` before closing. So `GZIPInputStream.close()` is indeed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are reading something using GZIPInputStream  in the `onPostExecute()` of async task which runs in UI thread. From 4.0 onward it is not allowed to have network connection in UI thread. I would suggest to move the GZIPInputStream  reading part in the `doInBackground()` method.

Edit1: or you can disable the strict mode by following code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```