# Android httpget does not work properly

Tags: android, http, url, get, execute

I am having a problem executing an url via httpget in android.

```
try 
    {   
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getURL = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/index.php?text=x");
        client.execute(getURL);
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "I'm here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Code Failed:" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

For some Reason my app wil show a Toeast with the message: "Code Failed: Null".
I just want to execute an URL. When the URL is called my php file will update a record in the database. I just want to update/insert databases in my mysql database. So parsing json/xml/other response is not necessary.

If I show my exceptions in the logcat, this is what I see:

```
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638): exception
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.thepl.shopapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:156)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-14 13:56:39.255: E/MYAPP(19638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638): exception
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.thepl.shopapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:156)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-14 13:56:58.205: E/MYAPP(19638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638): exception
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.thepl.shopapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:156)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-14 13:56:59.100: E/MYAPP(19638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638): exception
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.thepl.shopapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:156)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-14 13:57:21.185: E/MYAPP(19638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Call `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block and post the exception please.

Comment: Not trying to do this on the main thread are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make network call on main UI thread. following is the definition of the exception:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

check out my answer on following post for solution:

[Can java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close cause android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200863/can-java-util-zip-gzipinputstream-close-cause-android-os-networkonmainthreadexce/13200979#13200979)

Comment: Thx for your awnser. I need to support from android version 2.3.3 (Ginderbread) and up. Httpget is supported for api level 10. I'm testing with a Samsung Galaxy S3 with android 4.1.

So the problem is that I test with android 4.1, do you know how to solve this for higher android versions?

My manifast has al the right permissions.

I dont have that much experience with android yet so I dont know much about multitreading.

Comment: Not yet, I edited my comment above. I was testing this in my mainactivity and later in my broadcast receiver. Like when a user unplugges the power cable.

Comment: as a general rule you should not make network call on UI thread. So use the AsyncTask or Background java thread for network call... you can also use HttpURLConnection for http communication.. check out its documentation at following link it also have sample code for HTTP GET, POST request: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I will try that. I added a peace of code in my main.

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

after that I get this message:
Unable to resolve host "url here"; No address associated with hostname.

Comment: I'm using an other URL, but its for a project for a customer, so I cant post it here.

Comment: make sure that your device/emulator can access that url by accessing that url from the browser...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the stacktrace is pretty useful. Strictmode is on which will throw an exception if you try doing long-running work on the main (UI) thread.

There are two rules to the Android threading model:

1. Don't do long work on the main thread
2. Don't update the UI from outside of the UI thread

You have violated the first of these rules.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific or give me an example? Thx